# reduce CSS code multiple css definitions for table

Tags: html, css

I have about 100 tables on my website the only way to access them with css is with the ID of those.

Code looks like this:

```
.tablepress-id-1 .row-1 td {
background-color: #ffffff;
color: #666666;
}
.tablepress-id-1 .row-2 td {
    background-color: #6666cc;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.tablepress-id-1 .row-3 td {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #666666;
}
.tablepress-id-1 .row-4 td {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.tablepress-id-1 .row-5 td {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #666666;
}
.tablepress-id-1 .row-6 td {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.tablepress-id-1 .row-7 td {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #666666;
}
.tablepress-id-1 .row-8 td {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.tablepress-id-1 .row-9 td {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #666666;
}
.tablepress-id-1 .row-10 td {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.tablepress-id-1 .row-11 td {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #666666;
}
.tablepress-id-1 .row-12 td {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.tablepress-id-1 .row-13 td {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #666666;
}

/* Widget TablePress [table id=2 /] */

.tablepress-id-2 tbody td {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666666;
}

.tablepress-id-2 .row-1 td {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #666666;
}
.tablepress-id-2 .row-2 td {
    background-color: #6666cc;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.tablepress-id-2 .row-3 td {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #666666;
}
.tablepress-id-2 .row-4 td {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.tablepress-id-2 .row-5 td {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #666666;
}
.tablepress-id-2 .row-6 td {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.tablepress-id-2 .row-7 td {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #666666;
}
.tablepress-id-2 .row-8 td {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Is there a way to reduce the code ... each table looks like the same and the id are incremental .tablepress-id-1 ... .tablepress-id-100

any ideas for me?

thanks

UPDATE:

code:

```
thead td {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666666;
    background-color: #000099;
}
/* Stuff you care about */
[class^="tablepress-id-"] tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #666;
}
[class^="tablepress-id-"] tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #6666cc;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

[image]

this is the goal how it should look like:

[image]

Comment: Why can't you use `table .row...`? Or, just start with `.row...`?

Comment: only the row element?

Comment: Yes, if all tables look the same.

Comment: U have about 100 tables on your website so u can give same class and different id to each table and apply all css on that class

Comment: Are you just alternating the `<td>` style for every other row?

Comment: yeah have to check if all tables are really the same :) bevore i reduce it to the .row stuff

Comment: @Felix if that screenshot is the intended layout, you should say so in the post. Also, clarify what the new code snippet is all about. Is that your new code? What you tried after the code above it? What? Please be specific, this way we can help you better without a lot of back and forth. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .table{
        width:100%; 
        border-collapse:collapse; 
    }
    .table td{ 
        padding:7px; border:#4e95f4 1px solid;
    }
    .table tr{
        background: #b8d1f3;
    }
    .table tr:nth-child(odd){ 
        background: #b8d1f3;
    }
    .table tr:nth-child(even){
        background: #dae5f4;
    }
</style>

<table class="table">
    <tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're trying to *"zebra stripe"* the rows. If that's the case then you could reduce it a lot to something like this:

```css
/* You may or may not need this */
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* Stuff you care about */
[class^="tablepress-id-"] tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #666;
}
[class^="tablepress-id-"] tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #CCC;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<table class="tablepress-id-1">
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I noticed that the second row is different from the rest but seems to be the only difference in an otherwise normal zebra stripe effect. Not sure if that is a selected/highlight row or what but here's a couple ways to achieve that.

```css
/* You may or may not need this */
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* Stuff you care about */
[class^="tablepress-id-"] tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #666;
}
[class^="tablepress-id-"] tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #CCC;
  color: #FFF;
}
/* This rule should come after the other two, using the cascade in CSS */
[class^="tablepress-id-"] tr:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #66C;
  color: #FFF;
}
/* or as a class to apply to a specific row */
[class^="tablepress-id-"] tr.row-highlight {
  background-color: #66C;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<table class="tablepress-id-1">
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-highlight">
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yeah thats looking got. but not working 100%. I've added my code and a screenshot above.

Comment: Please be clear on what part _isn't_ working for you.

Comment: the thead should got a different color then the normal rows

Comment: added a example above how it should look like. there is no table head
first row whie, second blue and then zebra white and grey

it only works if I use .tablepress-id-1 ... only .row-1 has no effect

Comment: @Felix The second code example in my answer shows you how to target a specific row (two different ways). That is how you could style the first/header row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use comma to select more than one item so:

```
h1, p { something }
```

will select both `h1` and `p` elements and also you can write a more general selector as **Mottie** suggested.
I mean if all your desired elements belong to some class you can use

```
.theClass {}
```

to achieve what you want.